# memcpy fails when trying to copy from mm_struct->start_code

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm experiencing some very odd behavior with the code segment pointed to by task->mm and I hope someone out there can help me out.  What I'm doing is pulling the code segment out and putting it in a buffer and then generating an HMAC from it.  Occasionally I'll get an Ooops! saying that the can't with the call stack terminating at memcpy().  What appears to be happening is that the data goes away in the middle of the copy process and it causes a page fault and then the Ooops.  I've searched far and wide for references to this seemingly  ephemeral nature of the memory used in mm_struct, but have found nothing.  I don't believe I'm doing anything controversial in the code;  here it is with comments etc removed for brevity.

```
struct mm_struct* __mm;
...

__mm = get_task_mm(__task);
if(likely(__mm))
{
    __buflen = (__mm->end_code - __mm->start_code);
    if(likely(__buflen > 0))
    {
        __buf = (unsigned char*)__get_buffer(__buflen);
        if(likely(__buf))
        {          
            preempt_disable();
            memcpy(__buf, (uint8_t*)__mm->start_code, __buflen);
            preempt_enable();

            mmput(__mm);

            if(unlikely(!__do_ntru_hmac(__buf, __buflen, __hmac)))
            {
                __retcode = 0;
            }

            __release_buffer(__buf, __buflen);
        }
        else
        {
            printk(KERN_ERR "[%s] Buffer allocation failure [%d]\n", __task->comm, __buflen);
            __retcode = 0;
        }

        ...
```

The memory allocation routines are simple and aimed at being able to allocate large blocks of memory at once.  They look like this:

```
void* __get_buffer(unsigned long __buflen)
{
    if(likely(__buflen <= KMALLOC_MAX_SIZE))
    {
        return kmalloc(__buflen, GFP_KERNEL);
    }
    else
    {
        return (void*)__get_free_pages(GFP_KERNEL, get_order(__buflen));
    }

    return NULL;
}

void __release_buffer(void* __buffer, unsigned long __buflen)
{
    if(likely(__buflen <= KMALLOC_MAX_SIZE))
    {
        kfree(__buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        free_pages((unsigned long)__buffer, get_order(__buflen));
    }

    return;
 }
```

The error seems to occur randomly and I can't tie it to a task, parent or any other components of struct task_struct.  I've tried mutexes and spinlocks to protect the memory during memcpy,  I've tried stopping the task altogether using set_task_state() and restarting  it after the copy, but nothing seems to stop the problem.

UPDATE: I'm still hammering away at this problem and though I'd toss in some more data.  Here's the Oops dump.

```
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229195] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 0804b000
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229199] IP: [<c1312dfd>] memcpy+0x1d/0x40
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229221] *pdpt = 000000002cf4c001 *pde = 000000003b72c067
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229223] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229225] Modules linked in: aerolock(OF) vmhgfs(OF) vmw_balloon psmouse snd_ens1371 serio_raw gameport snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm snd_seq_midi btusb snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_timer snd_seq_device vmwgfx snd ttm drm bnep rfcomm soundcore mac_hid bluetooth snd_page_alloc vmw_vmci i2c_piix4 parport_pc ppdev shpchp lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid pcnet32 mptspi ahci libahci mptscsih mptbase floppy mii vmw_pvscsi vmxnet3
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229256] CPU: 0 PID: 2880 Comm: aerolockd Tainted: GF          O 3.11.0-17-generic #31~precise1-Ubuntu
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229258] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 07/31/2013
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229259] task: f1816700 ti: ed774000 task.ti: ed774000
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229262] EIP: 0060:[<c1312dfd>] EFLAGS: 00010202 CPU: 0
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229264] EIP is at memcpy+0x1d/0x40
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229266] EAX: ecc80000 EBX: 00011cd0 ECX: 00003b34 EDX: 08048000
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229268] ESI: 0804b000 EDI: ecc83000 EBP: ed775e74 ESP: ed775e68
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229269]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229271] CR0: 80050033 CR2: 0804b000 CR3: 2d9d5000 CR4: 001407f0
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229345] Stack:
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229347]  00011cd0 f1816700 f33703b4 ed775eb0 f9ba3a1b 0000063b 00000000 00000000
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229353]  0000063c c1b80e4c f1816700 ed775ee0 08048000 ecc80000 00000000 f1816700
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229358]  f9baa952 f1816700 ed775f08 f9ba3b6e 00000000 00000000 00000000 c1b9d642
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229364] Call Trace:
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229370]  [<f9ba3a1b>] __generate_hmac+0x8b/0x190 [aerolock]
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229373]  [<f9ba3b6e>] __validate_hmac+0x4e/0x220 [aerolock]
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229377]  [<f9ba3da0>] ret_do_fork+0x60/0x70 [aerolock]
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229384]  [<c167f12a>] trampoline_handler+0x11a/0x1c0
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229390]  [<c10839a4>] ? wake_up_new_task+0xe4/0x150
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229394]  [<c1054bf5>] ? SyS_clone+0x25/0x30
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229397]  [<c1054bf5>] ? SyS_clone+0x25/0x30
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229400]  [<c167efee>] kretprobe_trampoline+0x16/0x38
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229404]  [<c167efd8>] ? kretprobe_trampoline_holder+0x8/0x8
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229406]  [<c167c937>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229408] Code: c3 90 8d 74 26 00 e8 33 fe ff ff eb e8 90 55 89 e5 83 ec 0c 89 5d f4 89 75 f8 89 7d fc 3e 8d 74 26 00 89 cb 89 c7 c1 e9 02 89 d6 <f3> a5 89 d9 83 e1 03 74 02 f3 a4 8b 5d f4 8b 75 f8 8b 7d fc 89
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229439] EIP: [<c1312dfd>] memcpy+0x1d/0x40 SS:ESP 0068:ed775e68
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229444] CR2: 000000000804b000
Mar 16 09:39:27 ubuntu kernel: [  324.229447] ---[ end trace 3c014cb0223fa59a ]---
```

I've tried a lot of different tacks but have met with failure on all.  copy_from_user() for example fails every time; sometimes not reading the whole request and sometimes returning a partial.  Every time it fails on a partial it does so on a page boundary--again making it seem like the memory is being taken away mid-copy.

Given that I'm hooking do_fork(), could the process just be transitioning from kernel space to user space while I'm trying to capture it?  As I mentioned before, I've tried stopping the current task and restarting post copy, but it has no effect.

Also interesting to note;  I've had the same (memcpy()) code running for six weeks straight under varying loads without a failure on a single processor ARM BeagleBoard Black running Ubuntu 12.04 (3.8.13-bone28). The problem only seems to happen on my x86 box running Ubuntu 12.04 and then only when I put a heavy load on it like starting Chromium.

Sorry to be so long winded here,  I'm stumped.

Any ideas?

Thanks again in advance,

Pete

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably copy memory directly from userspace, as you've discovered.

Use `copy_from_user()` instead of `memcpy()`.  And don't disable preemption, there's no point.

Comment: Thanks caf,  I had thought of that and just tried it again, and it misbehaves.  When it hits the `copy_from_user(__buf, (uint8_t*)__mm->start_code, __buflen);` it crashes to the command line, locks the kernel and leaves the message -- **init: Error while reading from descriptor: Bad file descriptor.**  This does raise an interesting question as to where the data actually resides. I'm catching the task at `do_fork()` and wonder if the data is actually all still in kernel space and when I try to go after it its in the process of being copied into userspace, hence starving `memcpy()`

Comment: @pjenney58: Are you trying to do this for a task other than `current`? You can't do that.

Comment: Hi caf, no, __task == current

Comment: @pjenney58: Is there an Oops when you experience the error using `copy_from_user()`? The `EBADF` error you're seeing from `init` doesn't sound like it's coming from a `fork()` call - are you hooking any other syscalls too? (`memcpy()` is certainly wrong, anyway - the virtual address given by `start_code` is in userspace, and that memory can require page faults to be serviced to read, which a `memcpy()` call from the kernel doesn't handle).

Comment: No, the system hard crashed--black screen, single line of text and frozen, no Oooops. I'm hooking do_fork and do_execve.  I've looked everywhere for a description of what the address's are and how to manipulate them but just can't find a thing.  I've been through the ELF loader code and address look to be in kernel space, at least when its coming up.

Comment: Those addresses are always userspace addresses.  The various segments of the ELF are directly mapped into the task's memory, as if with `mmap()`.  `start_code` is set to the virtual address of the lowest mapped `PT_LOAD` segment, and `end_code` to the end of the highest mapped one.

Comment: Thanks @caf:  I've managed to get copy_from_user to work without crashing--I had a timer thread running that once removed, the copy_from_user stopped crashing.  Now I have exactly the opposite as with memcpy, and that is that copy_from_user fails all the time except occasionally.  Recall that memcpy() worked almost all the time and failed occasionally. It still seems that the data may be in motion from kernel to user space. I'm going to try a delay timer to allow all the data to make it to user space and then try a copy_from_user. Worth a shot...

Comment: I assume `copy_from_user()` is failing by returning nonzero? The "data in motion" idea is not the case, the file pages are demand-loaded and `copy_from_user()` will sleep until the necessary data is faulted in (which is why disabling preemption around it doesn't make a lot of sense).

Comment: Hi @caf, thanks for the explanation, the behaviour doesn't match though.  `copy_from_user()` never seems to finish -- it returns a few bytes and then no more, like the data's not there.  I've tried this loop to give it time like I would servicing a write, something like:`while((__readlen = copy_from_user(__buf, (uint8_t __user *)__offset, __buflen)) > 0){
      __diff = __buflen - __readlen;
      __buf     += __diff;
      __buflen  -= __diff;
      __offset  += __diff;
}`  but it just spins off into oblivion.

Comment: @pjenney58: The return value of `copy_from_user()` is the number of bytes it *couldn't* read (because that memory isn't readable by that userspace task), so a zero return is complete success, and anything less than `__buflen` is partial success.

Comment: Hi @caf: Yes, I understand that. I've tried several strategies to make copy_from_user work, but it fails most of the time.  It seems that the memory is just not there any more--its a mystery.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really believe in mysteries of this nature! It's *possible* to have an ELF file where there are two X segments with a gap between them - or to have an executable unmap its own binary - but both of those cases would be very unusual.  If `__task` is always `current`, why are you using `get_task_mm()` and `mmput()`? You can always directly access `current->mm` from process context, its necessarily pinned.

Comment: Hi @caf: As I understand it, get_task_mm() increments the users count, `atomic_inc(&mm->mm_users)` locking it and mmput() decrements the users count allowing it to be released--if users is 0;  Everything I've read says this should be done if one is to monkey with the mm_struct.

Comment: That's unnecessary for `current->mm`, because the current process necessarily already has a reference to its own mm and the mm use count is already incremented for that reference.

Comment: Hi, I am curious if you figured out why this copy operation fails once in a while? I am looking for a similar operation to basically have a program read its entire code segment and apply a crypto has on it. I assume this has nothing to do with how many pages are actually loaded as whatever is not loaded should be paged in as a result of this copy invocation